# Why computers programmer use 16 bit hexadecimal not 32 bit number system for represting binary coded values?

Tags: debugging, binary, hex

Hexadecimal numerals are widely used by computer system designers and programmers, as they provide a human-friendly representation of binary-coded values. but what is the problem with 32 bit number system for now.

Comment: There is no problem with 32 bit numbers, It is just easier to represent bits in Hexadecimal as you mentioned.

Comment: I think there is one standardization problem but shall we adopt 32-bit system in the near future?

Comment: I think you are missing the point. Computers use binary, humans use hexadecimal to read it easily. Why is the need for adoptation :)